# How do I find out how many connections are going into an Oracle Database?

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

We are working on a fairly old batch application that has a few connections to an Oracle database, it uses mybatis or jooq, depending on how old the codebase is.

We gotten an alert yesterday regarding the number of connections that are occurring are about to exceed the max. And the cause is most likely from us.

Is there anyway I can find out how many connections are going to the Oracle Database from our application? We are using the Intellij Idea IDE Ultimate edition if that helps.

Comment: Depending on the DataSource implementation, you might get access to the number of active Connection(s). But that also depends on how your application is run. Is it a single instance? Is it clustered/distributed?

Comment: *"the cause is most likely from us"* Try the duplicate link to show **all** connections on the database, then you'd know for *sure* who it is, instead of *guessing*.